# How to combine logs from two IIS servers to be fed into a Stat Report Generator like AWStats

Tags: iis, logging, windows-server, iis-8.5, awstats

I was given this interesting task in my new job of setting up an automated report on page hits for a site loadbalanced on seperate IIS servers. My first choice in terms of which software to use is AWStats as I am familiar with it from my Apache past but I wasn't sure what would be the best way of combining the stats between the two servers. Merging log files, pre AWStats with a script or 3rd party app? Possibly a setting within IIS? or maybe AWStats can do this itself? RegEx?

Forgive my ignorance, your answers are greatly appreciated, I would love to know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished writing a console app that we will run nightly with the task scheduler to merge the log files from the different servers we have on the load balancer.

Comment: That sounds perfect. Care to share?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using Outlook in background mode on our azure server and ran a 3rd party app that processes attachments. Has been up for a week with no issues. I recommend if you go down this path you monitor it using an app such as Zabbix or Nagios.